# Scope of a function parameter powershell

Tags: function, powershell, event-handling, parameter-passing, scopes

I'm creating a 3D Tic Tac Toe. I have created an array in which I store an information about what's inside a blank space in playing field(in my case blank space is a button and each of buttons has one element of array assigned to it "n" - nothing "o" - circle and "x" - cross). Then i created a function in which i defined filling in those blank spaces and after that i came into a problem. Element of an array is being passed via parameter of function and I dont know how to properly define a scope so an information would properly be stored in my array. Here's my code:

```
[array] $Field = New-Object "object []" 27
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 27; $i++) {
    $Field[$i] = "n"
}


Set-Variable -Name who -Value $true -Scope Script
Function filling {
    Param(
        [string]
        $F,
        [int]
        $a,
        [int]
        $b
    )

    if ($F -eq "n") { 
        if ($Script:who -eq $true) {
            $Button[$a, $b].Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Desktop\SYOP\kolko.jpg")
            $F = "o" 
            Set-Variable who -Value $false -Scope Script
        }

        else {
            $Button[$a, $b].Image = [System.Drawing.Image]::FromFile("$env:UserProfile\Desktop\SYOP\krzyzyk.jpg")
            $F = "x"
            Set-Variable who -Value $true -Scope Script
        }
    }
    $Wybor[$a, $b].Enabled = $false
}

for ([int]$i = 0; $i -lt 9 ; $i++) {
    for ([int]$j = 0; $j -lt 3 ; $j++) {
        if ($i -lt 9 -and $j -eq 0) { 
            $Button[$i, $j].Add_Click( { filling -F $Field[$i] -a $i -b $j }.GetNewClosure()) 
        }
        elseif ($i -lt 9 -and $j -eq 1) {
            $Button[$i, $j].Add_Click( { filling -F $Field[($j*10 + $i) - 1] -a $i -b $j }.GetNewClosure()) 
        }
        elseif ($i -lt 9 -and $j -eq 2) {
            $Button[$i, $j].Add_Click( { filling -F $Field[($j*10 + $i) - 2] -a $i -b $j }.GetNewClosure()) 
        }

    }
}
```

Later i created an if statement checking every possible winning scenario and thats how i know it doesnt work.

```
if(($Field[0] -eq $Field[1] -and $Field[1] -eq $Field[2] -and $Field[0] -ne "n" ) -or
        ($Field[3] -eq $Field[4] -and $Field[4] -eq $Field[5] -and $Field[3] -ne "n" ) -or
        ($Field[6] -eq $Field[7] -and $Field[7] -eq $Field[8] -and $Field[6] -ne "n" ) -or
        ($Field[0] -eq $Field[3] -and $Field[3] -eq $Field[6] -and $Field[0] -ne "n" ) -or
        ($Field[1] -eq $Field[4] -and $Field[4] -eq $Field[7] -and $Field[1] -ne "n" ) -or
        ($Field[2] -eq $Field[5] -and $Field[5] -eq $Field[8] -and $Field[2] -ne "n" ) -or
         ...
```

Comment: So, you want to write something back to `$field[$x]` from inside the `filling` function?

Comment: Yes, and I'm trying to accomplish that via parameter but i don't know if it is possible

Comment: Instead of passing `$field[$i]`, you'll want to pass `$i` by itself, then access `$field` by index from inside the function